# Ubuntu 23.10 installation on old PC won't boot without USB memory stick

Tags: boot, system-installation, 23.10

I have an old PC (~11 years old) with

- Gigabyte GA-H61M-HD2 motherboard
- SSD drive (I think it was running Ubuntu 22.10)
- Hard drive (`/home` files)

I tried to install Ubuntu 23.10 on it from a USB memory stick. Install appeared to go fine, however, after installation, the PC gets stuck indefinitely on the "American Megatrends" splash screen.

I found that I can't even press the <kbd>Del</kbd> key at start-up to enter the BIOS settings screen when in this situation.

However, I found that if I boot with the Ubuntu installation USB memory stick plugged in, then I *can* press <kbd>Del</kbd> to enter the BIOS settings screen, or, it apparently boots normally from the SSD. Once it gets to the point of starting to boot, I can remove the USB memory stick without a problem.

But I can't get the PC to boot normally from the SSD drive when the USB memory stick isn't plugged in. I have tried:

- Fiddle with the boot device order in the BIOS settings.
- Reinstall Ubuntu, booting from the USB memory stick in either UEFI or legacy mode. I *think* it then tries to install Ubuntu on the SSD to boot in either UEFI or legacy mode. But I'm not 100% sure about this.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, which is to flash the motherboard with a newer version of the BIOS.

[GA-H61M-HD2 (rev. 1.0) Support | Motherboard - GIGABYTE Global](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-H61M-HD2-rev-10/support#support-dl-bios)

The motherboard had BIOS version F2. I updated it to version F4a.

1. Download the `mb_bios_ga-h61m-hd2_f4a.zip` file from the Gigabyte web site.
2. Extract the zip file.
3. Copy the file `H61MHD2.F4a` to a USB memory stick formatted as FAT (FAT32 I guess).
4. Boot the PC, and press <kbd>Del</kbd> to enter the BIOS (I had to have the Ubuntu install USB plugged in for this step).
5. Select the Q-Flash utility in the BIOS.
6. Navigate to the USB memory stick that has the `H61MHD2.F4a` file, and then select that file.
7. Wait for the flash update to complete.

After this, the PC is able to boot Ubuntu 23.10 normally.